# Can one use still use the Chernoff Bound even when one doesn't know the expected value but a lower bound on it?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the case were we have a usual indicator random variable $T_i$. But we only know a lower bound of the probability of success, say $Pr[T_i = 1] \geq \frac{1}{2}$ (so we only know a lower bound on its expectation).

Let $T = \sum^k_{i=1} T_i$. Say that I am interested in finding what values of $k$ make the following true (for any given $\epsilon > 0$):

$$ Pr\left[T \geq \frac{k}{2} \right] \geq 1 - \epsilon$$

Using the Chernoff bound we have:

$$ Pr[T \geq c Ex[T] ] \leq e^{-a Ex[T]} = e^{(c ln(c) - c + 1)Ex[T]} $$

But we (obviously) know $Ex[T] \geq \frac{k}{2}$. Can we still use the chernoff bound to choose such a $k$? I feel it should be easy but I am rather stuck.

Comment: You don't need to know the expectation exactly for a Chernoff bound to be valid.  But you do need $> 1/2$, not just $\ge$, as the bound becomes trivial at $p = 1/2$.

Comment: @AlexR. I am interested in finding the probability of the majority of my $T_i$'s to be 1. Is it still an issue? Btw, you are right, my variables are not indicator, they are just bounded between 0 and 1.